# Can I replace text in the cells returned by sort function inplace

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, substitution

Is it possible to replace some text in cells that are returned by `=sort(indirect(), 2,0)` function without creating a temporary sheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, why not. example:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUBSTITUTE(SORT(INDIRECT("A1:B"), 2, 0), "abc", "xyz"))
```

if its something more advanced you can use `REGEXREPLACE` instead of `SUBSTITUTE`

Comment: It worked but it is losing some formatting from the the source cells.